# how to generate the JFR and Heap dump reports in linux servers?

Tags: java, linux, heap-memory, jfr

how to create the jfr and heapdump reports in linux servers?

> **Blockquote**

Answer (score 1):

With JFR we see the Live Objects on the Java heap **without** a `costly` heap dump.

Heap dump could be not needed anymore, in fact. This one of the key points of JFR.

Reference

- https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2020/09/02/Hunting-down-memory-issues-with-JDK-Flight-Recorder/
- https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Fix-Java-memory-leaks-JVM-heap-dumps-Recorder-Mission-Control